# react with TS - using setInterval with useEffect() how to send the request and only then start the interval

Tags: reactjs

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      backendAPIAxios.get(`/history${search}`)
      .then((response: AxiosResponse<IHistoricPricesResponse>) => {
        if (!response.data.success) {
          return alert(`Failed to get historic prices with error: ${response.data.message}`)
        }

        sethistoricPricesState(() => response.data.data!);
      })
      .catch((e: AxiosError) => {
        alert(`Failed to get historic prices with error: ${e}`)
      })
    }, 300000);

    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [sethistoricPricesState]);
```

The broblem is that when I load the page first time I need to wait for the interval, how can I send the request for the first time and only then start it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All kinds of ways of doing this.
For instance, why not simply export it to a separate function and call it twice?

```js
const fetchData = () => {
   backendAPIAxios.get(`/history${search}`)
      .then((response: AxiosResponse<IHistoricPricesResponse>) => {
        if (!response.data.success) {
          return alert(`Failed to get historic prices with error: ${response.data.message}`)
        }

        sethistoricPricesState(() => response.data.data!);
      })
      .catch((e: AxiosError) => {
        alert(`Failed to get historic prices with error: ${e}`)
      })
};

useEffect(() => {
   fetchData();
   const interval = setInterval(() => fetchData(), 300000);
   return () => clearInterval(interval);
}, [sethistoricPricesState]);
```

Or you can transfer `interval` to the component's scope,
(since you still need access to it in the cleanup function),
and set it in `fetchData` instead.

Whatever you prefer and makes more sense to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this :-

```
const fetchAPIData = () => {
  return backendAPIAxios
    .get(`/history${search}`)
    .then((response: AxiosResponse<IHistoricPricesResponse>) => {
      if (!response.data.success) {
        return alert(
          `Failed to get historic prices with error: ${response.data.message}`
        );
      }
      sethistoricPricesState(() => response.data.data!);
    })
    .catch((e: AxiosError) => {
      alert(`Failed to get historic prices with error: ${e}`);
    });
};
useEffect(async () => {
  async function call() {
    const res = await fetchAPIData();
    //process res
  }
  call();
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    call();
  }, 300000);

  return () => clearInterval(interval);
}, [sethistoricPricesState]);
```